# BIND round robin dns: how to make nslookup reply with just one ip address

Tags: dns, bind, rounding

I use bind round robin ,and there are multiple A record for one domain.But when I use nslookup test the resolution, it reply all the ip. is there any way that just reply one hit ip? 
any idea? thanks alot.

Comment: No, there isn't, but why would you want it do reply with just one address?

Comment: because I don't want some people get all my ip easily.

Comment: All they would have to do to get all the addresses is query multiple times. I din't think this makes much sense as a motivation.

Comment: Although it's kind of silly to do this for security, I have seen nameservers configured to work this way, and I'd like to know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Celada points out, doing this for the sake of security is silly, because someone could just keep trying until they get all of them.

*However*, there is still a way to do this, and people might have reasons to do it, or at least, like me, be curious how it is done.

That is the `order random_1` option for `named.conf`

*Big scary warning*: [this option will break DNSSEC, is intentionally "almost completely undocumented" and is "generally the wrong answer"](http://bugs.debian.org/581857).

It genuinely does seem [pretty completely undocumented](https://www.google.com.au/search?&q=%22order+random_1%22) and perhaps only present as a patch in Debian/Ubuntu bind, not upstream.

Comment: Care to mention what the reasons are for doing this?  I can't think of any good ones.

Answer (score 2):

Order random_1 was added to the Debian bind9 package specifically to address the useless-outside-of-your-corporate-network RFC 3484, which presumes that more bits of network match imply closeness, even if there's only two bits of commonality vs one.

A better solution to that situation would be anycast or some other selection that would defeat windows use of that RFC.  See also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968920